# Access retrofit server request and response time Android

Tags: android, retrofit

I can see that whenever I make a web svc call, I get the response in log. But I am finding it difficult to actually access that information in my code. For eg how do I find out the server request time and response time that I can see from the following log.

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Date: Tue, 21 Oct 2014 12:35:26 GMT
OkHttp-Received-Millis: 1413894922514
OkHttp-Response-Source: NETWORK 200
OkHttp-Selected-Protocol: http/1.1
OkHttp-Sent-Millis: 1413894921354
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
transfer-encoding: chunked
```

Answer (score 4):

Library and versions that I am using :

`Retrofit` version : `2.1.0`

`okhttp` version : `3.3.1`

`logging-interceptor` version : `3.3.1`

> This method only works within `onResponse()`.

If you debug the `onResponse()`, you will see the `sentRequestAtMillis` & `receivedResponseAtMillis` in the `rawResponse` part as in the image below.

These are the parameters which hold the time in milliseconds when the request was made and when the response was received respectively.

[image]

The following example illustrates how to get the values in those parameters programmatically after response is received.

````
retrofitRequest.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> 
        // time when the request was made to server, which you get from ```sentRequestAtMillis```
        long requestTime = response.raw().sentRequestAtMillis();

        // time when the response was received, which you get from ```receivedResponseAtMillis```
        long responseTime = response.raw().receivedResponseAtMillis();

        //time taken to receive the response after the request was sent
        long apiTime =  responseTime - requestTime;
    }

    @Override public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {

    }
});
````

Note that you may need to handle the code for any exceptions that may occur.

Comment: Have you noticed that this approach is not consistent with the time reported from `HttpLoggingInterceptor`? AFAIS, it's giving about half of it.

Answer (score 3):

In Retrofit < 2.0, use the RestAdapter.setProfiler() to get metrics on your requests.

Warning - [this will been removed in Retrofit 2.0](https://github.com/square/retrofit/pull/629) and will be replaced by a generalized interceptor system.

For example:

```
new RestAdapter.Builder()
    .setEndpoint("http://www.google.com")
    .setProfiler(new Profiler() {
        @Override
        public Object beforeCall() {
          return null;
        }

        @Override
        public void afterCall(RequestInformation requestInfo, long elapsedTime, int statusCode, Object beforeCallData) {
          Log.d("Retrofit Profiler", String.format("HTTP %d %s %s (%dms)",
              statusCode, requestInfo.getMethod(), requestInfo.getRelativePath(), elapsedTime));
        }
    })
    .create(MyService.class);
```

Here is some sample output:

```
D/Retrofit Profiler﹕ HTTP 200 GET /users/me (200ms)
```

Answer (score 2):

In your callback you have an access to `Response` object which has [`getHeaders()`](https://github.com/square/retrofit/blob/master/retrofit/src/main/java/retrofit/client/Response.java#L74) method, giving you a bunch of [`Headers`](https://github.com/square/retrofit/blob/master/retrofit/src/main/java/retrofit/client/Header.java).

As you can see, `Header` is just a name-value pair, so I think there won't be any problems to process them.

Comment: How to get Response in Synchronous retrofit calls?

Comment: @SoH, according to docs, "For access to the raw HTTP response use the Response type. `@GET("/users/list") Response userList();`" If you are interested in getting an object rather than just response, take a look at [how to extract it from the Response object](https://github.com/square/retrofit/blob/master/retrofit/src/main/java/retrofit/RestAdapter.java#L347]).

Comment: Thanks Smileek. Your comment really helped alot. I just have one more question. For Retrofit with Return type how do I access the Response type, given that I have my custom object specified for return type.

Comment: @SoH, you should revert your point of view: put `Response` as a return type and then extract your object: [link](https://github.com/square/retrofit/blob/master/retrofit/src/main/java/retrofit/RestAdapter.java#L347]). You can't get `Response` from your object, but you can get your object from `Response`.